# Changing a div space with a table

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have these three spaces that are blank to start with. I want to change using innerHTML in JavaScript.

```
<p id="topname"></p>
<div id="table"></div> 
<p id="botname"></p>

document.getElementById("topname").innerHTML = "Boy"; 
document.getElementById("botname").innerHTML = "Girl";
```

I managed to change topname and botname with the innerHTML. How do I change *div id="table"* to display an x by y (2x2, 4x4, 8x8,etc.) table?

Comment: Why not use real table? You can't really "convert" `<div>` to `<table>`, best you can do is **add a table** to the `<div>` placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *replacing* the `<div>` with a `<table>`, it is recommended to create a `<table>` as a child node of the `<div>` As long as you have not added additional styling to the `<div>` (like padding or margins), this will have no effect on the display.

A couple of loops to build `<tr>` and `<td>` will do the job.  Here's a function that takes x and y:

```
function makeTable(rows, cols) {
  // Create a table node
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  // Make a <tr> for each row
  for (var i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    // And make a <td> for eah col
    for (var j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      // Append them to the current tr
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    // Append the row
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }
  return tbl;
}

// Create a new 2x4 table with the function
var newTable =  makeTable(2, 4);
// And append it as a child to the <div id='table'>
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(newTable);
```

#### [Here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ehgYL/2/)

Comment: Was going to post something very similar, here is [my test case](http://jsfiddle.net/5Q3gF/). :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a follow up question. If there was content on that <div> (in your code's case the word "Content"), how do I replace that with a table through a JS function? Is it possible for appendChild to replace an existing text or table?

Comment: @user1584575 To fully replace the current contents, you can just blank out the existing `innerHTML`.  `document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = '';` then `appendChild(newTable)` as I have done above.

Comment: There's an `outerHTML` property that can be used, but I don't think it is standard and supported everywhere. Better to empty out the existing contents then append the new contents.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it the same way, however, that div id might be giving you issues. TABLE is an html entity unto itself. I would rename that.

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "<table><caption>Caption</caption><thead>Table Header</thead><tfoot>Table Footer</tfoot><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

And what Shadow Wizard said above. It is best to use the right tool for the job. My answer is solely if you insist on doing it within a div.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your `div` to a `table` manually:

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

With following code you can fill your `table` with rows and columns:

```
document.getElementById("table").appendChild(makeTable(2, 4));

function makeTable(rows, cols) {

    var table = document.createDocumentFragment(), tr = document.createElement("tr"), td = document.createElement("td"), i, j;

    for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) tr.appenChild(td.cloneNode(true));

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) table.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true));

    return table;

}
```